# Assign foreign key by rules

Tags: sql

I created an app to store payments and automatically categorize them by their data, for example `title`, or `recipient`. This is the database schema:

```sql
create table payment
(
    id int,
    title text,
    recipient text,
    amount int,
    category_id int null
);

create table category
(
    id int,
    title text
);

create table assign_rule
(
    id int,
    description text,
);

create table assign_rule_category
(
    id int,
    assign_rule_id int,
    value text,
    category_id int
);

insert into payment values
(1, 'internet bill', 'electric company', 100, null),
(2, 'money', 'Mike', 200, null),
(3, 'food ordered online', 'BestPizza', 80, null);

insert into category values
(1, 'FOOD'),
(2, 'LOAN'),
(3, 'BILLS');

insert into assign_rule values
(1, 'TITLE_CONTAINS'),
(2, 'RECIPIENT_CONTAINS');

insert into assign_rule_category values
(1, 1, 'bill', 3), -- if 'title' contains 'bill', then assign payment to 'BILLS' category
(2, 1, 'food', 1), -- if 'title' contains 'food', then assign payment to 'FOOD' category
(3, 2, 'Mike', 2); -- if 'recipient' contains 'Mike', then assign payment to 'LOAN' category

select * from payment;
```

Now I would like to get all payments with their categories, which should be:

| id | title | recipient | amount | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | internet bill | electric company | 100 | 3 |
| 2 | money | Mike | 200 | 2 |
| 3 | food ordered online | BestPizza | 80 | 1 |

I can only manage to do this in 2 separate sql -> first I fetch `payment` table, then `assign_rule_category` table, and join them together in backend code. Is is possible to have it all in 1 sql query?

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN the two tables payment and assign_rule_category and use below query:

select p.id,p.title,p.recipient,p.amount,arc.category_id from payment p
LEFT JOIN assign_rule_category arc
ON p.id = arc.assign_rule_id

Comment: I dont think you undestand the problem. There is no comparing payment's `title` or `recipient` data with rules